# Проблема с импортами в TypeScript+React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webstorm

Работаю в WebStorm, недавно начал пересаживаться на typescript, но тут возникла проблема. Есть уже работающий проект на чистом React, где я все компоненты на всякий в .tsx формат перевел. Но ts ругается на .tsx расширение, а без него не работает проект
(Светлая тема чтобы было видно)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что показывает `WebStorm` при наведении мышкой?

Comment: Добавил подсказку

Comment: Ошибка вам ни о чём не говорит?

Comment: Так я пишу о том, что если .tsx убрать будет ругатся уже не webstorm, а webpack, он не находит такие модули. ```Create React App``` использую

Comment: Приложите к вопросу настройки WebPack-а

Comment: Я использую ```Create React App``` он сам настраивает его, я конечно могу правку в вопрос ввести с кодом, но там 150+ строк кода только для одного скрипта (start, dev и тд)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142015/discussion-between-daskis-and-eziomercer).

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в самой сборке create react app, если пересоздать с '''--template typescript''', то все нормально